# Can I run GCOV on the same c file multiple times with different defines?

Tags: c, code-coverage, lcov

Can I test the same C file multiple times with different defines? Let's say one time with:

```
#define url google.de
```

and one time with:

```
#define url google.de/
```

Comment: use your compiler option, for example, `gcc -D url=google.de; gcc -D url=google.de/`, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: or change include path to a directory containing a .h file with some defines or others depending on the directory. This at least forces rebuild if there's an automatic dependency check. Using -D forces to do a cleanup